# Missing Template Splash Page Index Error

Tags: templates, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, haml

I get the following error when loading the root page of the server:

Template is missing

Missing template splash/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}.

My splash index page is in app/views/splash/index.html.haml

routes.rb:

```
root 'splash#index'
post '/signup' => 'splash#signup', as: :splash_signup
get '/spash' => 'splash#index'
```

The root used to direct to app/views/home/index.html.erb but I removed it and any relating code. Could this be causing my error somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handlers listed in your error message appear to be missing a handler for haml:

```
:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}.
```

Adding `gem "haml"` to your `Gemfile`, running `bundle install` and restarting your Rails server should fix this.

You can add the `haml-rails` gem instead if you want to have your generators use haml as the default for templates generated using Rails' built-in generators.

More info on haml can be found here: https://github.com/haml/haml
The haml-rails documentation is here: https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I just forgot to add the gem.